# jupyter-console fails to start, but jupyter-notebook is fine

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I can start jupyter-notebook but not jupyter-console.  In the dev virtualenv on a Mac, it tries to import `cast_unicode_py2` from `IPython.utils.py3compat`, but `cast_unicode_py2` can't be imported:

```
(dev) C02ZV35VLVDL:profile_default harvey$ jupyter-console
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/harvey/dev/bin/jupyter-console", line 5, in <module>
    from jupyter_console.app import main
  File "/Users/harvey/dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_console/app.py", line 26, in <module>
    from jupyter_console.ptshell import ZMQTerminalInteractiveShell
  File "/Users/harvey/dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_console/ptshell.py", line 22, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.py3compat import cast_unicode_py2, input
ImportError: cannot import name 'cast_unicode_py2' from 'IPython.utils.py3compat' (/Users/harvey/dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py)
```

Answer (score 10):

Short answer:

As a temporary workaround you can change line 22 of *[jupyter_console/jupyter_console/ptshell.py](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_console/blob/master/jupyter_console/ptshell.py)* to read:

`from ipython_genutils.py3compat import cast_unicode_py2, input`

On your computer, the file to edit is */Users/harvey/dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_console/ptshell.py*.

Longer answer:

*Jupyter console* is trying to import
`cast_unicode_py2` and `input` from `IPython.utils.py3compat`
but they've been moved to `ipython_genutils.py3compat`. This hasn't been fixed yet in the master branch of *Jupyter console*.

Answer (score 0):

After downgrading ipython to the previous version it worked again. I guess `cast_unicode_py2` is deprecated.

Comment: Leave the guess away and check it in `IPython.utils.py3compat` or search on the website of IPython to find your answer. Answers are not for "guessing" but for solutions. Please update your answer to avoid removal of answer.

Comment: Well, we don't have a good explanation for what is wrong in new ipython (see my message below), but it is correct to say that installing older ipython solves problem.  This lets me use Python again: "conda install ipython=7.10.2"

Answer (score 0):

Something is out of whack in anaconda now because even with a brand new virtual environment, jupyter-console produces same type of error, even though the ptshell.py file was *already changed on the source server* to the format you recommend.  I see

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pauljohn/LinuxDownloads/anaconda3/envs/fuzzymatch/bin/jupyter-console", line 7, in <module>
    from jupyter_console.app import main
  File "/home/pauljohn/LinuxDownloads/anaconda3/envs/fuzzymatch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_console/app.py", line 26, in <module>
    from jupyter_console.ptshell import ZMQTerminalInteractiveShell
  File "/home/pauljohn/LinuxDownloads/anaconda3/envs/fuzzymatch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_console/ptshell.py", line 22, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.py3compat import cast_unicode_py2, input
ImportError: cannot import name 'cast_unicode_py2' from 'IPython
```

Does this output give you enough info to guess what is wrong?

```
$ conda list --explicit
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: linux-64
@EXPLICIT
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/_libgcc_mutex-0.1-main.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/ca-certificates-2019.11.27-0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/ld_impl_linux-64-2.33.1-h53a641e_7.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/libstdcxx-ng-9.1.0-hdf63c60_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/libgcc-ng-9.1.0-hdf63c60_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/expat-2.2.6-he6710b0_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/gmp-6.1.2-h6c8ec71_1.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/icu-58.2-h9c2bf20_1.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/jpeg-9b-h024ee3a_2.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/libffi-3.2.1-hd88cf55_4.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/libsodium-1.0.16-h1bed415_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/libuuid-1.0.3-h1bed415_2.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/libxcb-1.13-h1bed415_1.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/ncurses-6.1-he6710b0_1.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/openssl-1.1.1d-h7b6447c_3.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/pcre-8.43-he6710b0_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/xz-5.2.4-h14c3975_4.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/zlib-1.2.11-h7b6447c_3.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/glib-2.63.1-h5a9c865_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/libedit-3.1.20181209-hc058e9b_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/libpng-1.6.37-hbc83047_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/libxml2-2.9.9-hea5a465_1.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/pandoc-2.2.3.2-0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/readline-7.0-h7b6447c_5.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/tk-8.6.8-hbc83047_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/zeromq-4.3.1-he6710b0_3.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/dbus-1.13.12-h746ee38_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/freetype-2.9.1-h8a8886c_1.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/gstreamer-1.14.0-hb453b48_1.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/sqlite-3.30.1-h7b6447c_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/fontconfig-2.13.0-h9420a91_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/gst-plugins-base-1.14.0-hbbd80ab_1.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/python-3.7.6-h0371630_2.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/attrs-19.3.0-py_0.tar.bz2
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/backcall-0.1.0-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/certifi-2019.11.28-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/decorator-4.4.1-py_0.tar.bz2
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/defusedxml-0.6.0-py_0.tar.bz2
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/entrypoints-0.3-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/markupsafe-1.1.1-py37h7b6447c_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/mistune-0.8.4-py37h7b6447c_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/more-itertools-8.0.2-py_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/pandocfilters-1.4.2-py37_1.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/parso-0.5.2-py_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/pickleshare-0.7.5-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/prometheus_client-0.7.1-py_0.tar.bz2
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/ptyprocess-0.6.0-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/pyzmq-18.1.0-py37he6710b0_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/qt-5.9.7-h5867ecd_1.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/send2trash-1.5.0-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/sip-4.19.8-py37hf484d3e_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/six-1.13.0-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/testpath-0.4.4-py_0.tar.bz2
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/tornado-6.0.3-py37h7b6447c_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/wcwidth-0.1.7-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/webencodings-0.5.1-py37_1.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/jedi-0.15.2-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/pexpect-4.7.0-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/pyqt-5.9.2-py37h05f1152_2.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/pyrsistent-0.15.6-py37h7b6447c_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/python-dateutil-2.8.1-py_0.tar.bz2
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/setuptools-44.0.0-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/terminado-0.8.3-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/traitlets-4.3.3-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/zipp-0.6.0-py_0.tar.bz2
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/bleach-3.1.0-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/importlib_metadata-1.3.0-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/jinja2-2.10.3-py_0.tar.bz2
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/jupyter_core-4.6.1-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/pygments-2.5.2-py_0.tar.bz2
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/wheel-0.33.6-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/jsonschema-3.2.0-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/jupyter_client-5.3.4-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/pip-19.3.1-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/prompt_toolkit-2.0.9-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/ipython-7.11.1-py37h39e3cac_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/nbformat-4.4.0-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/ipykernel-5.1.3-py37h39e3cac_1.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/nbconvert-5.6.1-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/jupyter_console-6.0.0-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/notebook-6.0.2-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/qtconsole-4.6.0-py_1.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/widgetsnbextension-3.5.1-py37_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/ipywidgets-7.5.1-py_0.tar.bz2
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/jupyter-1.0.0-py37_7.conda.utils.py3compat' (/home/pauljohn/LinuxDownloads/anaconda3/envs/fuzzymatch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed as of jupyter console 6.1.0 and available via conda.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it helps to

```
pip install ipython-genutils
```